# How to insert a widget twice at the same time in CKEditor?

Tags: widget, ckeditor

I need to insert a widget twice but with different additional classes, something like that:

```
[div 'open' with class "tabs"]
<br />
[div 'close' with class "tabs tabs-end"]
```

This does not work:

```
template:
    '<div class="tabs">Open</div> <br /> <div class="tabs tabs-end">Close</div>',
```

it just adds the first div completely ignoring the second one (and the `br`). Why is that?

Full code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'tabs', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'tabs',

    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.widgets.add( 'tabs', {
            allowedContent: 'div(!tabs,tabs-end)',
            requiredContent: 'div(tabs,tabs-end)',
            template: '<div class="tabs">Open</div> <br /> <div class="tabs tabs-end">Close</div>',
            button: 'Create Tabs',
            upcast: function( element, data ) {
                return element.name == 'div' && (element.hasClass( 'tabs' ) || element.hasClass( 'tabs-end' ));
            }
        }
    );

        editor.ui.addButton( 'tabs', {
      label : 'Tabs erstellen',
      command : 'tabs'
    });
    }
} );
```

I've also tried using an "insert" event to then just add the widget again with `editor.execCommand()` but the events wont fire at all and obiously should only fire once I insert the widget via ui button, else this would be an infinite loop I guess

Comment: When asking one question in many places it's worth cross linking that. The answer has been given on http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/How-to-add-a-widget-twice-via-template-property

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor widget must be a single element while you use document fragment – a collection of elements (see [`widget#element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-property-element)).

The fix is simple: wrap your elements in `<div>` so

```
<div class="tabs">Open</div> <br /> <div class="tabs tabs-end">Close</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-start">Open</div> <br /> <div class="tabs-end">Close</div>
</div>
```

and update your `upcast`/`downcast` accordingly.

Comment: but this would create 1 widget, i need 2 seperate widgets with space inbetween

Comment: Create two widgets with `editor.widgets.add( 'tabs-start|end', { ... } )` then. Currently there's no support for nested widgets e.g. you cannot create a parent widget, which would hold `tabs-start|end` and `<br\>` in between. Why do you need 2 separate widgets anyway?